# why does list_blobs returns virtual directory as well?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I thought it only return the leaf blob files and that has been the case earlier, but now all the sudden it returns the virtual directory as well, did I have the wrong impression or is it that something changed over the night?

Assume I have the following structure

```
container/dir0/dir1/blob1.json
container/dir0/dir1/blob2.json
```

And the following code

```
blobs = blob_service_client.list_blobs('container', 'dir0/')
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

will return

```
 dir0/dir1
 dir0/dir1//blob1.json
 dir0/dir1//blob2.json
```

instead of

```
 dir0/dir1//blob1.json
 dir0/dir1//blob2.json
```

anyway to not having the virtual directory as one blob returned in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this done by using the `BlockBlobService` class.

```
pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0
```

You can use either list_blobs() or list_blob_names() method to list the blobs inside the specified container. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<ACCOUNT_NAME>"
CONTAINER_NAME = "<CONTAINER_NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<SAS_TOKEN>'

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

print("\nList of blobs in "+CONTAINER_NAME+"\n")
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME,'dir0/')
for blob in generator:
    print(blob.name)
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]